# Creating an Algorithm in Java

Tags: java

Could you please help me solve this java algorithm?

the idea is to create a method that counts a number from -5 to 30 and then it goes down -1 till reaches -5 then starts again

for example method should return: -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, … , 25, 30, 29, 28, 27, … , -3, -4, -5, 0, 5,..

I have tried the following, but still I cant find a solution.

--

```
double a = -5;

 public double methodx(){

  boolean positiveDirection = true;

  if(positiveDirection == true) {

  if(a != 30) {

  a += 5 ;   
  positiveDirection=false;
  return a;    
} 
  else  {
  a -= 1;
  positiveDirection=false;  
}
}return a;
```

Comment: where do you call `methodx`? This is missing a loop somewhere.

Comment: Why do you use `double`? Use `int` for this case.

Comment: `positiveDirection` should be stored outside of the method because now it will always be set to true

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print that numbers, you can try this 
The `loop` variable indicates how many times you want to print that sequence of numbers

```
    public void methodx(){
    int loop = 2;
    while(loop != 0){
        for(int i = -5; i <= 30; i+=5){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        for(int i = 29; i >= -4; i--){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        loop--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void counter(){
        int number = -5;
        int direction = 1; // -1 negDirection , +1 pos direction
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(number) + ',');
            if (direction < 0) {
                number = number - 1;
                if (number == -5)
                    direction = +1;
            } else {
                direction = 1;
                number = number + 5;
                if (number == 30)
                    direction = -1;
            }
        }
}
```

You can convert 100 to any number you want